# FlutterFlow: How to use a custom function to get an array of timestamps between two different times?

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

So im trying to get an array of timestamps from 2 times in flutterflow.
ex. time1 06:00, time2 06:05
the result would be 06:00, 06:01, 06:02, 06:03, 06:04, 06:05.

Im using a custom function so somebody please help

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '../../flutter_flow/lat_lng.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/place.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '/auth/firebase_auth/auth_util.dart';

List<DateTime> occupiedTime(
  DateTime from,
  DateTime to,
) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  List<DateTime> occupiedTime(
    DateTime from,
    DateTime to, [
    Duration duration = const Duration(minutes: 1),
  ]) {
    List<DateTime> timestamps = [];

    while (from.isBefore(to) || from.isAtSameMomentAs(to)) {
      timestamps.add(from);
      from = from.add(duration);
    }

    return timestamps;
  }

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

i tried this code but no matter what i try to return it gives me error

Comment: why you defined `occupiedTime` method inside `occupiedTime` method?

Comment: remove
```
List<DateTime> occupiedTime(
  DateTime from,
  DateTime to,
) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE
```
and
```
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: I removed and its still the same

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input & output, you are trying to get List time (interval based on minute).

It can be

```dart
  List<DateTime> occupiedTime(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    final differenceInMinutes = to.difference(from).inMinutes;
    return List.generate(differenceInMinutes, (index) {
      return from.add(Duration(minutes: index));
    });
  }
```

While you like to format, you can use [packages/intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) or

```dart
  String getTimeString(DateTime dateTime) {
    return '${dateTime.hour}:${dateTime.minute}';
  }
```

Test snippet

```dart
  final result = occupiedTime(DateTime.now(), DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 5)));
  final stringTime = result.map((e) => getTimeString(e)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method like this:

```dart
List<DateTime> occupiedTime(
  DateTime from,
  DateTime to, [
  Duration duration = const Duration(minutes: 1),
]) {
  List<DateTime> timestamps = [];

  while (from.isBefore(to) || from.isAtSameMomentAs(to)) {
    timestamps.add(from);
    from = from.add(duration);
  }

  return timestamps;
}
```

Usage:

```dart
void main() {
  DateTime time1 = DateTime(2023, 1, 1, 6, 0);
  DateTime time2 = DateTime(2023, 1, 1, 6, 5);

  List<DateTime> result = occupiedTime(time1, time2);

  for (DateTime timestamp in result) {
    print(timestamp.toString());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2023-01-01 06:00:00.000
2023-01-01 06:01:00.000
2023-01-01 06:02:00.000
2023-01-01 06:03:00.000
2023-01-01 06:04:00.000
2023-01-01 06:05:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback, i tried Hamed's solutions and it gives me this warning, The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'List<DateTime>', is a potentially non-nullable type. Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

I tried giving it the nullable option but when i test run it returns null value

Comment: @ConOther please add your code.

Comment: i updated the code in the thread @Hamed

Answer (score 0):

### Code snippet suggestion

**@Con other** thanks to your imports, the suggestion was made inside the `/// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE` and `/// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE` comments. Therefore, the following code snippet only focuses on these lines (inclusive, hopefully for ease of understanding & copy and paste :)).

For now, the following code snippet may serve as a simple suggestion for your use case:

```
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  if (from.isAfter(to)) {
    throw ArgumentError(
        "Input of 'from' needs to be before 'to', thank you very much :)");
  }

  Duration duration = const Duration(minutes: 1);

  List<DateTime> timestamps = [];

  while (from.isBefore(to) || from.isAtSameMomentAs(to)) {
    timestamps.add(from);
    from = from.add(duration);
  }

  return timestamps;

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
```

*Short Note*:
The code snippet suggestion seems to run perfectly fine according to the four later shown tests. Thanks to `FlutterFlow v3.1` running `Flutter 3.10.4` on Friday, August 4th 2023, the code snippet suggestion could be tested four times. Of course the code snippet suggestion might work differently in another version.

### Four simple code tests

Disclaimer: Please be mindful that for the tests, every line above `/// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE` was copied on top of the **Code snippet suggestion**.

Thanks to FlutterFlow's built-in `Test Function` feature, attached you find two simple screenshots for the four tests, two each.

#### Test one and two

The green borders may help you to focus on the key information in the following screenshot for the first two tests. Furthermore, to the right you could inspect the `Return Value` and `Arguments`, if interested.

[Test one and two screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BJiZ.png)

#### Test three and four

Again, the green borders may help you to focus on the key information.

[Test three and four screenshot, with custom error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvnVG.png)

For test four, you can see the custom error message highlighted by white borders. Of course everyone is free to adjust this custom error message to their liking :)